# Obtain a visa "in", "from" or "at" the embassy?

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition in this statement?

> I obtained my visa at/in/from the Embassy of the Republic of ...

I have a visa now, I visited an embassy, made all the procedures and successfully obtained my visa. And now I want to tell a person where I got my visa.

Comment: It depends on what you mean. Any of those may be appropriate.

Comment: @Robusto, no special meaning. I just want to tell a person where I got my visa, in what embassy. I mean, I have a visa now, I visited an embassy, made all the procedures and successfully obtained my visa.

Comment: Most likely you would use "at" in that case.

Comment: I'd use "from".  I received my visa from the German Embassy.  Or "My visa was issued by the German Embassy."  To Robusto's point, technically you'd go ***to*** the embassy and if someone asked "Where do you go to get a visa?", you can say "You have to apply ***at*** the embassy."

Comment: A tiny detail. These days it's very unusual to get a visa literally at the Embassy: it's always a visa "service center" (typically run by VFS Global or some other outfit).

Comment: You obtain things "from" a source.

Answer (score 1):

If you visited the embassy, use ***at.*** *At* is used to signify presence at a place; it's fairly general and is normally the first choice for a locational preposition referring to a building or an address.

If it's important to note that you were inside the building, use ***in.*** This is more specific than *at,* so it's only used if it makes an important distinction.

*From* doesn't indicate where **you** were; it indicates the origin of the visa. You would have got the visa *from* the embassy even if you had received it by post.

Answer (score 0):

at/in/from may fit.

- You need a visa to enter India and you can apply for it **at** the Indian Consulate in...
- To enter the U.S. you have to apply for a visa **at** the American Consulate in...
- I got my visa **from/at/in** the French Consulate in Norway.

But you can also apply for your visa **online**.